# has_many to has_many to has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an application that has the following models:
- Category
- Subcategory
- Product
- ProductSubcategory

My relations are the following:

```
Category has_many :subcategories

Subcategory belongs_to :category
Subcategory has_many :product_subcategories
Subcategory has_many :products, through: :product_subcategories

Product has_many :product_subcategories
Product has_many :subcategories, through: :product_subcategories
```

I want to access all the products from a category. What's the best way? I tried Category has_many :product_subcategories, through: :categories, but it didn't work. Is there anyway I can do it?

EDIT: In sql code, my problem would be solved with this sql query:

```
    SELECT products.* FROM products
INNER JOIN product_subcategories
  ON product_subcategories.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN subcategories
  ON product_subcategories.subcategory_id = subcategories.id
INNER JOIN categories
  ON categories.id = subcategories.category_id
WHERE
  categories.id = 1;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does your `schema.rb` look like?

Answer (score 0):

You want to establish the relation through `Subcategory`, i.e.:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, through: :subcategories
end
```

Comment: I tried it, but I receive the following error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass